# MS CRM 2011 Port Forwarding Error(Without IFD)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

One of our client wants to do port forwarding to the crm server , so that users can access the crm from Internet. They are using ZyXel firewall (for port forwarding).

They have mapped 203.xx.xx.xx(public ip) to 192.Xx.xx.xx(local ip) with incoming and outgoing port 5555(default port of our crm server), but it  doesn't work. Any suggestions?

I tried to map for rdp and sql report server(web server), these things are able to access.

I have been stuck with this more than a day. Can anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

It's more common to see full IFD implementation with crm 2011, since SSL allows for more security. I do think it's possible to configure CRM to work with just regular port forwarding though, although I have never done it myself.

Take a look here: http://www.mscrmguru.com/2013/05/exposing-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.html

> Examples of software that can be used for port forwarding includes
>   Microsoft Forefront Treat Management Gateway (TMG) and Microsoft
>   Forefront Unified Access Gateway. Basically what it comes down to is
>   the following:
>
> 1. The user enters an internet address e.g. http://crm.mycompany.com.au
> 2. The internet address is recognised and points to the external
>      registered IP address e.g. 162.123.123.11
> 3. The external IP address is redirected to your internal IP address
>      through your reverse proxy / tunnelling / port forwarding e.g.
>      10.0.0.10
> 4. The user enters username and password and gets authenticated.
> 5. The Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 pages is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue by binding port 80 to the crm website in IIS. Not sure why 5555 port didnt work, even though the port is opened in the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a corresponding Policy Control to pair with the corresponding NAT rule otherwise when the NAT / port forwarding rule is applied, it will be directed to the stateful packet inspection part of the device controlled by the Policy Control rules and be dropped from that point forward.

Policy Control is found by selecting the Configuration menu option (looks like two yellow gear or cogs whatever you call them), then selecting Security Policy, then Policy Control.

The rule structure is similar to NAT, except on this screen you permit or deny traffic based on ZONES that maps to any physical or logical interface configured. In most cases, you want to permit port 5555 traffic coming from the WAN zone from ANY IP address, to the LAN, DMZ or VLAN zones to the IP of the host or object configured in the ZyXEL firewall.

You'll want to ensure that port 5555/TCP or 5555/UDP, whichever is applicable to permit, is configured as a Service Object under the Configuration->Object->Service menu.

Configuring the service before will allow easy setup afterwards when setting your NAT and policy rules, because you'll be able to select the new service object instead of entering ports only. It's also required to set a service object anyways for all Policy Routes.

It feels like the work has been done twice, but NAT and Policy Routes are two different things that have to be configured to allow most kinds of non-standard traffic. You admin might have had an easier time configuring other rules such as HTTP, FTP, SMTP and various common services, because the firewall has built-in objects for those services, which makes configuring rules for services running non-standard high-range ports a little but more tricky.